# push a forked repository which contains sub modules

Tags: git, github

I`ve forked a repository which contains one submodule, I cloned the repo and its submodule to my laptop and made some changes to the source code and the submodule and pushed them to my repository.

after checking my repository, I noticed that changes I made to the submodule, didn`t pushed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forking the repo doesn't fork the submodule: make sure you have the right to push to that submodule repo.
And making changes to a submodule means you need to push to the submodule upstream repo from within said submodule.

```
cd /path/to/repo/submodule
# changes
git add .
git commit -m "Changes to submodule"
git push
```

And then you need to add the new [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) to the [index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309):

```
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Record new submodule state"
git push
```